# JDBC Connection from MySQL to JSP Site

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to connect MySQL to a JSP website. Here are the steps followed so far:

1. installed MySql
   When I open `MySQL command line client` I am prompted for a password, the same I entered during installation.
   I am able to create databases and tables, insert rows into tables etc. I have an admin and a user.
   `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` returns: `root@localhost`
2. I needed a MySQL connector, so I went here:
   http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-3.0.9-stable.zip and downloaded this zip file:
   `mysql-connector-java-3.0.9-stable.zip`
3. I unzipped the archive, took the jar file called `mysql-connector-java-3.0.9-stable-bin.jar` and placed it inside the Tomcat website folder:

   > C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
   >   5.5\webapps\DataAccess\WEB-INF\lib

(this .jar is supposed to be copied to the WEB-INF\lib\ folder of each web application that needs to access a database; I also have JSTL jar files there that work well)

4. I created this script called booklist.jsp:

> "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   5.5\webapps\DataAccess\booklist.jsp"

:

```
   <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>

    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt" %>

    <sql:setDataSource var="datasource"    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/rentbooks"
                       user="root" password="1234"/>
    <sql:query dataSource="${datasource}" var="result" > SELECT id, title, authors FROM book   </sql:query>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>A First JSP Database</title
      </head>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
             <td>id</td><td>title</td><td>authors</td>
          </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var="row">
          <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${row.id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.title}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.authors}" /></td>
          </tr>
    </c:forEach>
       </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Not sure why at this stage I get an error :

```
type Exception report exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /booklist.jsp:10
9:  user="root" password="1234"/>
10: <sql:query sql="SELECT id, title, authors FROM book" var="result"
11:     dataSource="${datasource}"/>
```

To be more precise about the error message: "Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 44"
Any help please? The database, tables and field names are correct. How do I know if it's related to the JDBC connector or if it can't connect to the database? Or if it connects but can't read the data? 
During the MySql installation I created a username, called sammy, but when I enter MySQL command line, the current user it returns is "root@localhost". 
Thank you in advance. I tried to detail the steps as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked after I replaced `mysql-connector-java-*-bin.jar` with the more recent version 5.0.8 (which I have found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html; I downloaded this zip file: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.zip, unzipped the archive, took the jar file called mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar and placed it inside the Tomcat website folder).

I restarted Tomcat and MySql and now it works.  By the way, the username I entered is `root`, although during installation I chose a distinct username. Not sure why.

I will leave this question here in case it helps others as well, especially since I detailed all of my steps.

Comment: Why have you edited the question on the concrete problem? Now it does not contain any answerable problem.

Comment: BalusC, I had added the connector detail before restarting Tomcat to realise that fixed my problem. 
I do agree with you, and have just edited the question according to your suggestion to reveal the correct and logical thought process. Thank you.